# Django - Media in production is not working

Tags: django, git, heroku, media, production-environment

My static files are working well, but my media ones have a problem. I already deployed my website in heroku and it is online in production. (DEBUG=False)
Look at the code:

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/'
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 
'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
cartaz = models.FileField(default='/static/images/logo.jpg')
```

index.html

```
<img src="{{campeonato.cartaz.url}}" class="img-responsive">
```

[My Github repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJVl.png)

Here is the problem, I was uploading an image in the admin section and then it worked well, but suddenly after a couple minutes the image disappeared from the website and I got the following error:

```
Not Found:/media/tdscampeonatos_rzFCbET.jpg
```

Then I added a media repository inside my project in github with the images I had uploaded:

[My Github repository after I added the media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhlXo.png)

Then the images I had added to the media repository worked, but the ones I didn't added was still not working. I uploaded some more images and I got the same error, because the images was not going directly to the media path I had created in the Github repository. 
5 days trying to fix this, I already looked for almost everything in internet. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deploying on heroku.  Probably the hobby plan. On this plan, the app is made to sleep when not active then  freshly redeployed when accessed. Thus the media files created during last run get deleted

You should upgrade your plan or consider using a thirdparty storage like cloudinary to store the media

Comment: Even on a fully paid plan, you cannot and must not store user-uploaded assets on the Heroku filesystem.