# Images are not shown on my heroku website. static files are loaded fine

Tags: django

In my website static files are loaded without problem. But media files under Training.image.url containing images are not loading.

I tried looking for solution online and on this forum as well but no solution. Following are small portion of my files.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb',
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
-------------------------------------------------------
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio/static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'
```

urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', Trainings.views.home, name = 'homepage'),
    path('blog/', include('Blog.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server is on debug False, by default Django do not serve static files. There is a help page on heroku about that specific problem : [Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

## Quick option: whitenoise

You can install a package to very quickly solve this issue. It is the actual solution suggested by Heroku.

> Django does not support serving static files in production. However, the fantastic WhiteNoise project can integrate into your Django application, and was designed with exactly this purpose in mind.

It only aks few lines on your `settings.py`

```
pip install whitenoise
```

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

## More complex option : django-storages

If you have more requirement regarding performance, I would suggest to give a look at [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to deploy on build all collectedstatic assets to a S3 instance which is design specifically for that purpose.

## hobby plan

Thanks to some search and this stackoverflow post: [Django - Media in production is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591985/django-media-in-production-is-not-working), it might also come from your current selected plan:

> You are deploying on heroku. Probably the hobby plan. On this plan, the app is made to sleep when not active then freshly redeployed when accessed. Thus the media files created during last run get deleted
>
> You should upgrade your plan or consider using a thirdparty storage like cloudinary to store the media

Comment: Didn't work. Is it because i haven't installed ' dj-database-url ' package?

Comment: `dj-database-url` is about writting `DATABASES` var in a single url, definitely not related. Do media files load on your machine ? Do you run collectstatic when building your app ? is debug false ?

Comment: yes locally they are visible in both debug-(false & true). But on heroku these are not.

Comment: Did you know the solution?

Comment: Just added an other suggestion, which might come from heroku specifically ... ca you confirm media files works at the beginning but then stop working after your instance reboot ?

Comment: yes when i set debug=True and add image files its showing them but after sometime they just disappear .    While when debug=False images are not visible even after fresh upload.